# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los caracteres que se repiten no se impriman dos veces?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código, lo que sucede este pido que el usuario ingrese una palabra y determina cuantas veces se repitió un carácter, ejemplo si ingreso la palabra Hoola la salida será:

h 1
o 2
o 2
l 1
a 1

quiero que las letras que se repitan solo se impriman una sola vez es decir que en el ejemplo anterior no se imprima dos veces la letra "o" es decir que la salida sea así:

h 1
o 2
l 1
a 1

cualquier sugerencia o aporte me serie de gran ayuda.

```
public class Contador {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        String palabra;
        
        char[]Arraypalabra;
        
        char caracter;
        
        int contador = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Escribe una palabra");
        palabra = sc.next();
        
        Arraypalabra = palabra.toCharArray();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < Arraypalabra.length; i++) {
            caracter = Arraypalabra[i];
            for(int j =0 ; j < Arraypalabra.length; j++) {
                if(Arraypalabra[j]== caracter) {
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("La letra:" + Arraypalabra[i]+" "+"Se repitio :"+contador);
            contador = 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero que esta solución te pueda ayudar

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena = "";
    char[] Arraycadena;
    char caracter;
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
    cadena = sc.next();
    Arraycadena = cadena.toCharArray();

    boolean[] yaEstaElCaracter = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
    int[] cuantasVeces = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE];

    for (int i = 0; i < Arraycadena.length; i++) {
        caracter = Arraycadena[i];
        if (Arraycadena[i] == caracter) {
            cuantasVeces[caracter]++;
        }
        yaEstaElCaracter[caracter] = true;
    } // Fin Para

    for (int i = 0; i < yaEstaElCaracter.length; i++) {
        if (yaEstaElCaracter[i])
            System.out.println((char) i + " " + cuantasVeces[i] + " veces.");
    }
```

Comment: Se agradece tu intento de ayuda, pero considera explicar cómo tu código puede ayudar, pues puede haber usuarios que no lo entiendan si no hay una explicación del mismo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

he agregado un `ArrayList` tipo `String` para almacenar las palabras ya ingresadas, luego valido si ya está almacenada antes de imprimirlas. He agregado comentarios donde he agregado nuevo código

```
public class Contador {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    String palabra;
    
    char[]Arraypalabra;
    
    //NUEVO ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> palabrasAlmacenadas = new ArrayList<>();
    char caracter;
    
    int contador = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Escribe una palabra");
    palabra = sc.next();
    
    Arraypalabra = palabra.toCharArray();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Arraypalabra.length; i++) {
        caracter = Arraypalabra[i];
        //Validar repetidos
        boolean flag = true;
        for(String pal : palabrasAlmacenadas){
            if(pal.equals(Character.toString(caracter))){
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        //Se Agrega al ArrayList
        palabrasAlmacenadas.add(Character.toString(caracter));
        
        for(int j =0 ; j < Arraypalabra.length; j++) {
            if(Arraypalabra[j]== caracter) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        //imprimir datos
        if(flag){
            System.out.println("La letra:" + Arraypalabra[i]+" "+"Se repitio :"+contador);
        }
        contador = 0;
    }
}
```